# Cannot connect to ASP.Net gRPC app in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have read that it is possible to host a gRPC app in IIS if you meet the criteria: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I have met the criteria (.Net7.0, windows server 2022), but I cannot create a connection. I **can** connect to the service if ran as a console app, but I would like to run it in IIS.

Here is what I have done:
Properly set the binding in IIS. I am connecting to https://192.168.1.30:5001
I have tried using HttpsSys with and without Kestrel:

```
builder.WebHost.UseHttpSys(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = false;
    options.Authentication.Schemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.AuthenticationSchemes.None;
    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
    options.MaxConnections = null;
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
    options.UrlPrefixes.Add("https://192.168.1.30:5001");
});

builder.WebHost.UseIIS();
```

I have tried using Kestrel without HTTP.sys:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(address), port, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
        if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
            listenOptions.UseHttps(certFile, password);
    }); ;
});
```

Here is what my web.config looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

There are no errors in the stdout file (or in Windows Event Viewer).

When I connect to the app by running the .exe console in the server, I can connect to the gRPC service from the client. In IIS, by app is under a subdirectory, so I connect like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new SubdirectoryHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), "/MySubDirectory"));

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(_dataServiceAddress, new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials),
    HttpClient = httpClient
});
```

The port does not appear to be open when I run the app in IIS. The specific error from the client is `Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

What am I missing?

Comment: I see two things that MAY be wrong. 1) TLS is performed before a request is sent.   If TLS fails the request is never sent and then you do not get a response which is what the error implies.  So you may need to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.  Depends on if the server is set to requires HTTPS. 2) You are using HttpProtocols.Http2 which may not be supported on an older OS like IIS.  Try HTTP 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: Thanks I will look into TLS. I am using https (see the IP address above). I also have the GoDaddy certificate in place. This is a brand new server with Windows Server 2022 as mentioned above. The build is 20348.1249.

Comment: You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see if TLS completed.  You will not see the HTTP Request being sent if TLS fails.  The sniffer will show version of TLS (either 1.2 or 1.3) and you will see a TLS certificate block sent from server to client with the certificate names.  One of the certificates has to be loaded into the client stores for both machine and user.  A route need to exist from client to server (and back) and you can use PING to test the route.